# How to change SWC component's width shown on the Flash IDE?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, movieclip, swc

I linked an item in library with an .as file.In this .as file,I write the class like this:

```
public class TextArea extends MovieClip 
{
    .......
    public function setWidth(w:Number):void
    {
         this.width = w;
    }
}
```

**Then I change the item to complied clip in library(It is same as complied as ***SWC*** )**.I add it into stage and change it's property to fire the setWidth function.But the width just doesn't change.What should I do to change the Movie Clip's width?

P.S. The child ,a TextField , in this item can be changed width.

[image]

In the pic, I put a SWC component on stage and the SWC only have one TextField as child.

The Text field is given black border and the SWC is being selected,the blue border is its bounds.

**And I print the `this.width` in text and the width is auto changed to adjust the text field.**

But the blue border is what I want to change.It shows on Flash panel and stand for the transform bounds like this:

[image]

So, I don't have any trouble to change children's data. And now I found the class is like this:

[image]

There is a LivePreviewParent as `this.parent`. It provide the live preview of my swc on stage.And the size I change is absolutely changed,but I think the blue border is stand for the LivePreviewParent's border.

However, change the size of LivePreviewParent is equal to change the component's size not the blue one.How strange the class is ! **So I want to know the blue one is actually the LivePreviewParent's border? If yes , how to change it?**

Comment: in `setWitdh` you are always setting 500. Shouldn't it be `this.width = w;`?

Comment: @taskinoor the default is 100 , now I set 500, it's still 100.And I found `this.width` is changed but the instance I put on the stage doesn't change width.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know, how is exactly your component builded, you should have inner logic to resize subcomponents/childs.

Universal solution, blind resize of every child:

```
public function setWidth(w:Number):void
{
    var i: uint, len: uint = this.numChildren, child: DisplayObject;

    for(i; i < len; ++i){
        this.getChildAt(i).width = w;
    }

}
```

If only textArea is one child:

```
public function setWidth(w:Number):void
{
    textArea.width = w;

}
```

Simple TextField container, with background and custom padding:

```
import flash.display.Sprite;
import flash.text.TextField;
import flash.text.TextFieldAutoSize;
import flash.text.TextFormat;

public class TextContainer extends Sprite {
    private var _textField:TextField;
    private var _padding:int;

    public function TextContainer(text:String, format:TextFormat, padding:int = 4) {
        _padding = padding;
        _textField = new TextField();
        _textField.defaultTextFormat = format;
        _textField.autoSize = TextFieldAutoSize.LEFT;
        _textField.multiline = true;
        _textField.wordWrap = true;
        _textField.text = text;

        addChild(_textField);

        _textField.x = _textField.y = padding;

        //Default width
        setWidth(100);
    }

    public function setWidth(value:Number):void {
        _textField.width = value;

        graphics.clear();
        graphics.beginFill(0xF0F0F0);
        graphics.drawRect(0, 0, _textField.width + 2*_padding, _textField.height + 2*_padding);
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
var textContainer: TextContainer = new TextContainer("Some text here for test, more text, for multi-line test and resize", new TextFormat("Arial"));
desiredContainer.addChild(textContainer);
textContainer.setWidth(200);
```

Comment: Yep, I don't know how complex his MovieClip is ;)

Comment: My MovieClip is very simple,it has only one TextField as child. I link the MC with AS and complied it as SWC.I can change TextField's width by `this.textIns.width` and `this.width` is also changed auto.But, the SWC component I put on the stage doesn't change its width I saw on panel in Flash.

Comment: I have added example, of the same text container, but with background and padding. Why do you work with your component in the Flash IDE? Instantiate it, place it whatever you want. Flash IDE doesn't provide clever instruments for resizing components with honour their children.

Comment: @NicolasSiver The graphics is always what I want , but the problem is the selection bounds in Flash IDE of my SWC component is not correct.And also the size shown on Flash IDE's panel is not correct.The number I want change doesn't related to the MC's width.So I have edit the problem.

Comment: What do you mean by SWC component? I think, you misunderstand main idea of how Flash IDE works. If you call SWC component simple library object with ActionScript export setting, that library object will not react on scene, on your actions. If you really want component with Live Preview, you can [create one](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/creating-flash-components-for-distribution--active-3846)

Comment: Thank you anyway,the SWC component is what your right click on the library item and choose the "export SWC file" generated. I want use code in swc or swf to impact Flash IDE's behavior. But I was wrong, there is no way adobe left to me at all.

Answer (score 0):

You have to change the width of 'this' relative to **something.**  The most likely thing is its container. So let's assume that your `TextArea` class is instantiated in your `Main` class as 'textarea'  In `Main` you'd write this: `textarea.width = 500`

Comment: It has been changed , but I found this is not I want.I have edit the question.

Answer (score 0):

Finally I found that there is an impassable wall between Flash IDE and the AS code in SWC. There is no way to access IDE's data from SWC.